# Start scraping as soon as DOM is ready Nightmarejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, electron, nightmare

I'm using [nightmarejs](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) and I have a problem that I don't know how to solve.

I use the instruction **goto(URL)** followed by the instruction **evaluate()** in order to perform some operation on the webpage.
The DOM is ready after 2-3 seconds but I believe that the instruction **goto()** waits for the full page download which is very heavy (it takes 6-7 seconds).

Is there a way to tell nightmare to start the evaluate() function as soon as the DOM is ready and NOT when the page is fully loaded?

Comment: Does the `DOMContentLoaded` event help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/800010/1042144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nightmare doesn't have support for passing extra arguments/options to `goto` function yet, nor it has the proper document about accessing window contents api provided by electron.

You can track if page loaded or not by `dom-ready` event, but you cannot probably do anything about it right now.

If there is a solution for this, I'll update the answer.